# C++ Windows Key Detection from Standard-In

Tags: c++, windows, io, user-input

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

constexpr auto KEY_FORWARD = 'w';
constexpr auto KEY_BACKWARD = 's';
constexpr auto KEY_LEFT = 'a';
constexpr auto KEY_RIGHT = 'd';
constexpr auto KEY_UP = 't';
constexpr auto KEY_DOWN = 'g'; 


bool updateKey(char keyValue, bool* key_control, KEY_EVENT_RECORD ker){
    if (ker.uChar.AsciiChar == keyValue) {
        *key_control = ker.bKeyDown;
        std::cout << ker.bKeyDown ;
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}

int main() 
{
    using namespace std;

    HANDLE hIn;
    HANDLE hOut;
    bool _continue = TRUE;
    INPUT_RECORD inRec[128];
    DWORD numRead;
    hIn = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
  
    bool left_control,right_control,up_control,down_control,forward_control,backward_control;
    left_control =  FALSE;
    right_control = FALSE;
    up_control = FALSE;
    down_control = FALSE;
    forward_control = FALSE;
    backward_control = FALSE;
    while (_continue) {
        if (!ReadConsoleInput(hIn, inRec, 128, &numRead)) {
            continue;
        }
        for (DWORD i = 0; i < numRead; i++) {
            if (inRec[i].EventType != KEY_EVENT) {
                continue;
            }
            if (updateKey(KEY_UP, &up_control, inRec[i].Event.KeyEvent)) continue;
            if (updateKey(KEY_DOWN, &down_control, inRec[i].Event.KeyEvent)) continue;
            if (updateKey(KEY_LEFT, &left_control, inRec[i].Event.KeyEvent)) continue;
            if (updateKey(KEY_RIGHT, &right_control, inRec[i].Event.KeyEvent)) continue;
            if (updateKey(KEY_FORWARD, &forward_control, inRec[i].Event.KeyEvent)) continue;
            if (updateKey(KEY_BACKWARD, &backward_control, inRec[i].Event.KeyEvent)) continue;

        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Above is a simple script that takes an input from standard in.

When I run this and press and hold the 'a' key effectively entering 'a' into standard-in I get "1010101010101010...." which tells me that the Windows API thinks that I am repeatedly pressing and releasing the key.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleinput) for ReadConsoleInput says that numRead should point to the number of input records outputted. Every time I press a key it sets numRead to 2. The two records each respectively correspond to the single key pressed, however, in one of the KEY_EVENT_RECORD(s) bKeyDown is 1 and in the second it's 0. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/key-event-record-str) for KEY_EVENT_RECORD says bKeyDown the value is set to true when the key is pressed and false when the key is released but this is not the behavior I'm observing.

What could possibly cause this?

EDIT(4-19-2021): Apparently double clicking the exe that is built from this script works fine. Only when I run the script from the command prompt or powershell is it that it loses it's mind.

Comment: You are probably observing auto-repeat. See what's in `KEY_EVENT_RECORD::wRepeatCount`

Comment: changing the output line to std::cout << ker.bKeyDown << ker.wRepeatCount;
 I now get repeated 1101s. If I'm reading this right then it is not considering it held down?

Comment: Seems like this API contains errors. When I run the code, it returns an `AsciiChar` = 30 for 'a' and `dwControlKeyState` = 97 (the real 'a' value). There were also known bugs in keys handling, for example this - https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/5342. Consider upgrading your Windows to the latest version and ask MS, when this does not help.

Comment: turns out if I run the exe then it works fine. But if I run it from powershell it fails in the way illustrated above. This machine has the newest version of Windows so if it's been resolved it's not that issue. I think I can live with working with the exe directly! Thanks for the help!